# Bootstrap Tag Toggles not working with symbols

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, html-entities

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap Tag Toggles](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). I generate them using PHP. Some of my links are composed of symbols. I cannot access theses links.

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TL9K/), namely the **Settings (%)** tabs.

I've tried to use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` to fix this but they do not convert these symbols.

I've used a `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '_', $foo)` to remove all non-alpha-numeric characters but that replace them all by a _. It's working.

However, this is problematic because:

`preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '_', 'Foo%%') == preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '_', 'Foo()')`.

I need something that would convert distinctively these character in some other character that jquery would accept.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You cant use (%) in an id. Just use "Settings" and you probably want to put the (%) in like <a href="#Settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings (%)</a>

Comment: Don't forget, it's jquery your using and jquery is Js and JS id's cannot start with a cyfer or have strange characters

Comment: Yes I agree with you all. But how can I convert these symbols so that I will not encounter a conflict beetween, for example, Foo%% and Foo().

Comment: I'm not getting your problem right. Cause looking at your fiddle you can just get away with the preg_replace. Just don't use the underscore. You are talking about something distinctive. You want to change some characters to something accepted in an id, but that limits to alphanumeric and underscore. And after you want to change it back or something?